# AWS RDS Reserved billing charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-reserved-instances

Hey I just want to know info about the reserved rds instance. Suppose one purchase an reserve rds plan for an year with no up front payment method. And there is no rds instance currently running that matches the same setting like db instance class etc as of the reserved one. Will I am going to charge for it or not, as reserve rds plan is of 1 year.
Thanks

Comment: You will be charged. Time is running from the purchase. That's what reservation means on AWS, you pay for hace sure that when you need you will have. Believe or not, the cloud isn't infinite, someday all the VMs could be in use. The upside is that you pay less for this reservation.

Comment: I have searched it, and every where I find is that you can't cancel reserve rds once purchased, is there really no way to cancel it. Because I need to do it, I am currently using no upfront payment method

Comment: Contact AWS Support, they may be able to assist you if you explain your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With reserved instances you pay for it, if you use it or not.